# How to import single dataset in palantir foundry without using tranform or tranform_df

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories, foundry-code-workbooks

I want to import one dataset globally so that I can access that the dataset within the file.
Is there any ways to import the single file without using `transform` or `transform_df` in Palantir Foundry code repository.

Basically I want to extract the data from the dataset and return all the values in terms of list. If I use transform or transform_df decorators then I won't be able to access that input file while calling the return function.

or Is there any other ways to return the list of values by using one data frame as an input to the function in palantir code repository.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate dynamic files using config file in palantir foundry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64587005/how-to-generate-dynamic-files-using-config-file-in-palantir-foundry)

Answer (score 1):

This question is a close duplicate of this question in intent (I've voted to close): [How to generate dynamic files using config file in palantir foundry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64587005/how-to-generate-dynamic-files-using-config-file-in-palantir-foundry)

#### Answer to the question in the title:

You can't use transforms to import datasets into foundry. You need to use data connection instead and create an ingest.

#### Answer to the question in the body:

As answered on your other question of "how-to-generate-dynamic-files-using-config-file-in-palantir-foundry". You cannot programmatically create transforms based on another datasets's content. The datasets are created at CI time.

You can however have a constants file inside your code repo, which can be read at CI time, and use that to generate transforms. I.e.:

```
myconfig.py:
dataset_pairs = [
  {
    "in": "/path/to/input/dataset,
    "out": "/path/to/output/dataset,
  },
  {
    "in": "/path/to/input/dataset2,
    "out": "/path/to/output/dataset2,
  },
  # ...
  {
    "in": "/path/to/input/datasetN,
    "out": "/path/to/output/datasetN,
  },

]

from myconfig import dataset_pairs

TRANSFORMS = []
for conf in dataset_pairs:
  @transform_df(Output(conf["out"]), my_input=Input(conf["in"]))
  def my_generated_transform(my_input)
     # ...
     return df

  TRANSFORMS.append(my_generated_transform)
```

To re-iterate, you cannot create the config.py programatically based on a dataset contents, because when this code is run, it is at CI time, so it doesn't have access to the datasets.