# loop through a list of tables and save to csv with table name

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I have a list of 120 tables and i want to save sample size of first 1000 and last 1000 rows from each table into individual csv files for each table.

How can this be done in code repo or code authoring.

The following code allows to save one table to csv, can anyone help with this to loop through list of tables from a project folder and create individual csv files for each table?

```
@transform(
    my_input = Input('/path/to/input/dataset'),
    my_output = Output('/path/to/output/dataset')
)
def compute_function(my_input, my_output):
    my_output.write_dataframe(
        my_input.dataframe(),
        output_format = "csv",
        options = {
            "compression": "gzip"
        }
    )
```

**psuedo code**

```
list_of_tables = [table1,table2,table3,...table120]
for tables in list_of_tables:
    table = table.limit(1000)
    table.write_dataframe(table.dataframe(),output_format = "csv",
        options = {
            "compression": "gzip"
        })
```

i was able to get it working for one table, how can i just loop through a list of tables and generate it ?
The code for one table

```
# to get the first and last rows 
from transforms.api import transform_df, Input, Output 
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id
from pyspark.sql.functions import col


table_name = 'stock'
@transform_df(
    output=Output(f"foundry/sample/{table_name}_sample"),
    my_input=Input(f"foundry/input/{table_name}"),
)
def compute_first_last_1000(my_input):
    first_stock_df = my_input.withColumn("index", monotonically_increasing_id())
    first_stock_df = first_stock_df.orderBy("index").filter(col("index") < 1000).drop("index")
    last_stock_df = my_input.withColumn("index", monotonically_increasing_id())
    last_stock_df = last_stock_df.orderBy("index").filter(col("index") < 1000).drop("index")
    stock_df = first_stock_df.unionByName(last_stock_df)
    return stock_df
```

```
# code to save as csv file
table_name = 'stock'

@transform(
        output=Output(f"foundry/sample/{table_name}_sample_csv"),
        my_input=Input(f"foundry/sample/{table_name}_sample"),
)

def my_compute_function(my_input, output):
    df = my_input.dataframe()
    with output.filesystem().open('stock.csv', 'w') as stream:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(stream)
        csv_writer.writerow(df.schema.names)
        csv_writer.writerows(df.collect())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best strategy here would be to programatically generate your transforms, you can also do a multi output transform if you don't fancy creating 1000 transforms. Something like this (written live into the answer box, non tested code some sintax may be wrong):

```py
# you can generate this programatically
my_inputs = [
   '/path/to/input/dataset1',
   '/path/to/input/dataset2',
   '/path/to/input/dataset3',
   # ...
]

for table_path in my_inputs:
   @transform_df(
      Output(table_path + '_out'),
      df=Input(table_path))
   def transform(df):
       # your logic here
       return df
```

Comment: Hi @fmsf, this snippet only returns one df, result_df , correct me if i am wrong , i need each table to be saved seperately, i was able to get it working for one table with two repos, i have updated my question with that

Comment: this worked for creating the dfs for all tables, but to write to csv we need to use @transform decorator, how can i change this logic to fit that ?

Comment: you can use the code that you had, I just wanted to highlight that you can wrap it around a for loop to generate all transfroms

Answer (score 1):

If you need to read the table names rather than hard coding them, then you could use the `os.listdir` or the `os.walk` method.

I think the previous answer left out the part about exporting only the first and last N rows. If the table is converted to a dataframe `df`, then

```
dfoutput = df.head(N).append(df.tail(N)])
```

or

```
dfoutput = df[:N].append(df[-N:])
```

Comment: Hi bill, unfortunately `os.listdir` and `os.walk` methods won't work within foundry file system, since the transform generation code runs at CI time, there are multiple questions in SO that mention this if you would like to read about it i.e.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64603638/how-to-import-single-dataset-in-palantir-foundry-without-using-tranform-or-tranf/64604913#64604913 . Thank you for the answer though! This would be a valid answer if it would be within another operating system. Not within Foundry OS though.

Comment: errata: `os.listdir` and `os.walk` will work, but will be executed within the CI checks, so you'll only discover files within your repo. At CI you don't have access to datasets or other foundry resources.